# Cql model error ModelMetaClass object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models, cassandra

Used Apps:

- django 1.9~
- [django-cassandra-engine](https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine)

When trying to register my model in admin site i get this error :

> Typerror: 'ModelMetaClass' object is not iterable

my models.py:

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine import models


class ApiModel(models.Model):
    id = columns.BigInt(primary_key=True)
    content = columns.Text()
    created_at = columns.DateTime()
```

my admin.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import ApiModel

class ApisAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(ApiModel, ApisAdmin)
```

As far as I know the cql engine doesn't have self **META** and by [this](https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine/issues/24#issuecomment-162964627) comment I have to set it by myself .

and now the question is , what should i do ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Could you please try it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add class 'Meta' into your class like this:

```
class ApiModel(models.Model):
    id = columns.BigInt(primary_key=True)
    content = columns.Text()
    created_at = columns.DateTime()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tablename'
        verbose_name = 'name_for_verbose_presentation'
        ... and so one
```

Since in your link author directly says that "cqlengine is about to be merged into python-driver soon. After that we can think about it, but it is important to know, that django-cassandra-engine never meant to be fully compatible with django models." you should be prepared that you could get another problems with it.
After you define Meta class, I belive that Django will trow another error, maybe because it missing some field. So you will need to addd needed fields.

**Update:**

So, looks like now I got the point. 
Take a look at this line in Django's `register` method:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L83

```
if isinstance(model_or_iterable, ModelBase):
            model_or_iterable = [model_or_iterable]
```

If you are registering default Django model, it will be instance of ModelBase and it will be wrapped into list. And if it is not, it will stay a class, and on the next line Django will try to iterate over the class and trow you not iterable exception.

And since you are registering not Django model, so it is not an instance of ModelBase. So, it will not be wrapped into list and you're getting your exception.

I'm not sure if it is 'right' way to workaround it, but I've tried to pass class wrapped into list and it worked for me:

```
admin.site.register([ApiModel], ApisAdmin)
```

Other way is to try make this model be an instance of ModelBase and or patch it private fields somehow or refactor models more deeply. But I'm not sure that it is a better way.

Comment: I see that django checks _meta field of the model. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L95 But I can find any mentions of some `ModelMetaClass`.

Comment: Model MetaClass is on db driver files . please check this https://github.com/Knotis/djangocassandra/blob/master/djangocassandra/db/meta.py

Comment: I believe here you're getting 'not iterable': https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L85 Django tries to iterate over Model, but it has no __iter()__ and next() methods python throws an Not Iterable exception. 
So you need to make it iterable.